# How to Apply Transforms to a VDB volume object

Tags: volumetrics, transform-orientation, asset-browser

I have imported a VDB file and it's orientation is wrong, but when I try to apply the location and rotation after orienting it in right direction, it doesn't work
It gives error - `"Objects have no data to transform"`
How can I apply transform, and also set the origin point to exactly center(currently it is at one corner of the VDB file.)

I wanted to save it as asset and then use it in asset browser, but If the Transforms are not applied it is imported with the wrong orientation, and it needs to corrected every time I import.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Is the goal only to move the origin and orientation or do you need to modify it or use it in geometry node or other (anything that could modify the vdb)?

Comment: No, the only goal is to move the origin and orientation

Answer (score 0):

As you do not need to modify the vdb model after it is imported, you can use collection instance and mark it as asset.

Here is an example moved from the origin and rotated:

[image]

Now, if you import this asset, the vdb will be like if it was parented to an empty which keeps position, rotation, etc defined in the asset file, but considered with no rotation or offset from the origin of the scene.

[image]